# OTRS with no text message in the body

Tags: python, otrs

I have made a script in python to automatically open tickets on OTRS.

```
SERVER = "mailserver.domain"
FROM = "ZABBIX<zabbix@domain>"
SUBJECT = "{0}-{1}[ZABBIX] Do something".format(date,hour)
TO = ["otrs.ticket@domain"] 
CC = someone@domain
BODY = "[{0}] Caracteres randomicos para evitar reabertura de chamado no OTRS\n\n\n".format(RANDOM)
REPLY = "dudeIT@domain"
Cmd = 'cat {2} | isql DATABASE01 {0} {1} -b -c -d, > {3}'.format(User,Pass,QuerySQL,FileTXT
Converte = 'unix2dos %s '% FileCSV

exec_query = os.system(Cmd)

tcsv = open(FileCSV,"wb")
ftxt = open(FileTXT, "rt")
for line in ftxt:
    tcsv.write(line.replace(',',';'))

tcsv.close()
ftxt.close()

exec_converte = os.system(Converte)

TEXT = MIMEText(BODY.encode('latin-1'),'plain')
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = SUBJECT
msg['From'] = FROM
msg['To'] = ', '.join(TO)
msg['Cc'] = CC
msg['reply-to'] = REPLY
destinatarios = TO + CC.split(",")
part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
part.set_payload(open(FileCSV,"rb").read())
Encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;
filename=List_Files.csv')`

msg.attach(part)
msg.attach(TEXT)
server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
```

While testing the script (sorry for the errors of bad practices and etc), everthing was fine, the body (text message) and the attachment was ok. But when I send the email to OTRS. The text don't appear in body of ticket, instead the OTRS show the message: "no text message = > see attachment.

Need help to fix this.[image: OTRS with no message in the body]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOund the solution.

I can't figure out what cause the problem, but sending out the message as HTML solved the problem.

```
BODY = "<html>
       <head></head>
        <body>
        <p>[{0}] Caracteres randomicos para evitar reabertura de chamado no OTRS
       </body></html>".format(RANDOM)

...
TEXT = MIMEText(BODY,'html')
```